# AppleScript, Receive "System Events got an error: Connection is invalid. (-609)" when Parsing Large XML Files

Tags: applescript

I've created an AppleScript to parse MS Word XML files in order to generate a tab-separated document to be opened in Excel. Everything works great for small to medium sized XML files. However, I receive the error, "System Events got an error: Connection is invalid. (-609)", when parsing larger files. Below is the tell block where the error occurs:

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    with timeout of 0 seconds
        set quit delay to 0
        set theXMLFile to XML file theDocument
        set theRecords to XML elements of XML element "wx:sect" of XML element "w:body" of XML element "w:wordDocument" of theXMLFile whose name is "w:p"
    end timeout
end tell
```

I've attempted to adjust both the timeout and quit delay parameters, including commenting them out, but I still receive the error even with these set to 0. I've tested the script to make sure it makes it passed the "set theXMLFile..." line, but does not make it passed the "set theRecords..." line.

To confirm there is not an issue with the XML file, I manually split the document into two smaller files. Each of these files processed just fine through the scrip. This leads me to believe the error is either to do the size of the theRecords variable or some sort of timeout as a result of the time it takes to parse the file.

Any help in resolving or troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: “Connection is invalid (-609)” indicates that System Events.app quit—or more likely crashed—in the middle of handling one of your commands. That would suggest a bug in SE, in which case you can try to rework your commands to avoid tickling that bug if possible. The alternative would be to use Cocoa’s NSXML classes via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge; the ObjC API is more complex but avoids having to go through SE (which, let’s be honest, is not the world’s best software).

Answer (score 0):

As I checked the problem is to using **whose** clause with property which is not direct property of XML elements. You can check this in the Script Debugger. Following works with large XML files. At least for me it worked:

```
-- set theDocument to "HARD_DISK:Users:123:Desktop:TEST files:SampleLarge.xml"
set aList to {}

tell application "System Events"
    activate
    tell (contents of XML file theDocument) to tell (XML element "w:wordDocument")
        tell (XML element "wx:sect" of XML element "w:body")
            set XMLElements to XML elements
            set XMLElementNames to name of XML elements
            repeat with i from 1 to count XMLElementNames
                if (item i of XMLElementNames) is "w:p" then
                    set end of my aList to item i of my XMLElements
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

return aList
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I set the timeout to 3600 seconds. Unfortunately, I received the same 609 error after the script was running for only 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I made the update, but am still receiving the 609 error.